# Advice on how to come out with a Comments / Social Network solution

Tags: comments, social-networking

Firstly I would like to say what a great site this is.

I am planning to add a Comments section to a mobile application (Android) I am writing.  One thing that I thought would be cool was to have all the Comments made by each user, available on a user home page.  So I have some questions

1. do you think this is a good idea?
2. is there an open source solution available?
3. any advice on the software architecture?

Answer (score 1):

Try Socialize: [www.GetSocialize.com](http://www.GetSocialize.com)

It offers in-app comments, likes, sharing + posting out to Facebook

Answer (score 0):

1. It totally depends on the application. If it's something where people might care about other people's comments then sure! Go for it! If it's an app that lets me write a diary, then no, don't let other users comment on it. We'd need more details on what your plans for the app are at the moment.
2. What have you got already and how do users log in? Presumably you have some server somewhere they log onto? The standard answer here would be to use Ruby on Rails (open source) and an open source plugin to get social networking functionality like comments ([Community Engine](http://communityengine.org/) for example).
3. What are you most comfortable with? The best architecture for your project is the one where you're most comfortable working. That's the one that's most likely to make the project a success.

Comment: Thanks.  The application allows user to play media streams from off the internet.  Logging in here is optional.  The Comments section would need to be run off a server and I have already set up a PHP development environment.  I am trying to figure out whether to go open source, implementing an API from a Social Network service or coding a rudimentary CMS with UserCake.